# how to call DataBinder.Eval dynamically from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

Code:
 i am using an  Repeater control here

```
<%# Container.DataItem != null && Container.DataItem.Equals(base.CurrentNode) ?
   "<li class=\"link active\">" :
   "<li class=\"link\"><a href=\"" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SiteURL") + "\">"
 %>
```

Now i need to call this method from .aspx page

```
protected bool CheckHideText(string name)
{           
    // Based on my condition i would return true or false  my logic goes in here..
}
```

Now i need to call this method CheckHideText from.aspx,

If value is returned true i new to show the link, otherwise if it is false i do not want the link not be visible

Answer (score 0):

You can always call a code behind method in aspx page

```
<%# CheckHideText(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SiteURL"))%>
```